# im trying to make my code detect what is a user and what is an admin then direct it to the correct page

Tags: php, authentication, admin

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connection.php';

$user_id = $_POST ['user_id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$query = "SELECT *  FROM Register WHERE username= '$username' AND  Password = '$password' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in the query: $query. " .     mysqli_error());



$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



if ($row ) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
echo '' . $username . '';
 &&  ($row ) {
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
header('Location: AdminPage.php');
}


else if ($row ) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
echo '' . $username . '';
header('location:Login.php');
 && ($row ) {
$_SESSION['user_id'] = > 1;
header('Location: ProtectedPage.php');
}

?>
```

can you help me with what is wrong with this code im trying to make it detect what is a user and what is an admin then direct it to the correct page. please if you are here to just rant about how vulnerable my code is to sql injections i really couldn't care less as this is for a project and i do not require it to be protected

Comment: This looks like PHP; if it is, please tag it so.  If not, tag it with whatever language it is.

Comment: cheers mate i forgot about php tag

Comment: The syntax is invalid. Unfortunately it is not trivial to correct it, since you do not offer enough information what exactly you require. For example: what is `$row`? Where does it come from? What does it contain?

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: `session_start();` loaded too?

Comment: that should make more sense now

Comment: yes session start is within connectuion.php

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) (i.e. none at all) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are looking for something like this:

```
if ( $row && is_array($row) && isset($row['username']) && isset($row['user_id'])) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
  $_SESSION['user_id']  = $row['user_id'];
  if ( 1==$row['user_id'] )
    header('Location: AdminPage.php');
  else
    header('Location: ProtectedPage.php');
} else {
  header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

This assumes that the user_id is stored inside the database and that user_id 1 indicates that this is "the" admin account.

Comment: ok thanks so this code should work, if i wanted to add error codes into this when the password is wrong how would i do that?

Comment: ive tried your code but whats it doing is counting everything as an admin i tried an acc with user_id 2 and it took me to admin page instead of protected page any ideas

Comment: Well currently a redirection header is sent, redirecting to the `Login.php` page. You cannot combine such a header and a message. You could add a message to the url you redirect to, so something like `header('Location: Login.php?message=login%20failed!');`, but that is not really elegant. Anyways, I suggest you first get this to work, then you go on with the next steps. One thing at a time.

Comment: The condition correctly tests for user_id 1. So if you are always redirected to page `AdminPage.php` then most likely your sql query is wrong. Try dumping the `$row` you get back from the query.

Comment: orite i understand that but what about the other comment ive made about every user is now being redirected to adminpage

Comment: Also I see in your edited question that you accept a user_id from the client: `$user_id = $_POST ['user_id'];`. That does not make any sense, sorry. You have to rely on the user_id from the database, otherwise a client could specify whatever user_id he likes to!

Comment: how do i dump the $row sorry im a bit of a noob with php

Comment: I suggest you start using google for such questions: "php dump variable"... Sorry, but I cannot give you an introduction into programming here...